# Adding google play services version to your app's manifest makes error

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to add google play services to my Android project. I followed the tutorial on the  [official site](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). The problem is that I get an error when I add the following code in the project's Manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The error is:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I have added the google play services  library in the same directory (COPIED IT). Also I have added it in my project as a library (Properties->Android->Add). I've cleaned the project more times then I can count. The API that the project uses is level 15, Android 4.0.3. And the google play services that I am using are the new ones not the froyo ones.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE

> I HAVE DONE THIS AND IT STILL DOESNT WORK
>
> 1.SDK manager -> extras -> Install package Google play servies
>
> 2.Import project ->
>
> Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-0130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject
>
> Add above project as a library project For followed way...
>
> 3.Right click Project -> properties -> android -> Is library -> add google play service

This is a part of my manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I checked The manifest of the google play services library (WHICH IS NOT FROYO) and this is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="3265130"
    android:versionName="3.2.65 (834000-30)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

</manifest>
```

which is the same as the froyo one. Can that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You Must add the library of the Google-play-services to your current project

**1.SDK manager -> extras -> Install package Google play servies**

**2.Import project ->**

**Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-0130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject**

Add above project as a library project For followed way...

**3.Right click Project -> properties -> android -> Is library -> add google play service**

All the best...It will work cent % If you have any doubt tell i will clarify...

Comment: Have you try this again and clean your project...It may possible to work